# How to get the volume GUID

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hardware

I am using win32 api with `C++`.

I would like to know how I can get the volume GUID using a "device path".

My device looks like this:

```
\\?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_0111#5&39fe81e&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: @codeka : i need to get the drive letter to map with the device path

Comment: You can ask this question as many times as you want, but the answer is not going to change.  The link that I posted in your other question shows how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the device with device instance ID `usb\VID_04f2&PID_0111\5&39fe81e&0&2`. That's probably a mass storage device aka disk. Now, the problem you have is that a mass storage device doesn't actually have a drive letter; it's the volume on that disk which has a drive letter. If there are two partitions, a single USB mass storage device may have two drive letters. So, there's no direct function to get *the* volume.

It looks like you need to enumerate the device tree rooted at `usb\VID_04f2&PID_0111\5&39fe81e&0&2` to find children with device type "volume". The DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE you get will have a `dbcc_name` field that you can pass to `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint()`.

Comment: Is there a way to use `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint` if the device is not mounted (e.g. if Windows runs out of drive letters)?

Comment: @ Judge Maygarden: I think you've got a mistaken asumption here. "Mounting" on Windows does not require a drive letter. The "Mount Point" used here (`dbcc_name`) certainly isn't a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered querying the WMI for it? Let me know if you need details on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

i do with win32api way