# which partition types (00..FE) can be accessed in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, disk-partitioning

In [mapping partitions starting from PhysicalDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672388/mapping-partitions-starting-from-physicaldrive) I use a code that mounts partitions of a certain type [0, 1, 6, 7, 11, 12, 114].
I want to extend the range for all partitions that can be accessed.
I found this: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html
Can someone tell me which one can be accessed on Windows XP without the help of another program?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP natively supports FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, and NTFS. Other file systems, such as HPFS, JFS, ext2/3, and ReiserFS can be supported through an IFS (Installable File System).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that helps (even thow I already knew them). So, numbers are [1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14]?